# .htaccess: Enable directory indexing for a certain user agent

Tags: .htaccess, if-statement, user-agent

The issue: I want to enable directory indexing for a certain directory on my server (it's disabled by default) only for a certain user agent.

I know that there are <If> instructions that can be used in a .htaccess file, but I have not managed to get a result.

What I'm looking for is something along these lines:

```
<If user-agent = 'a certain user agent'>
    Options +Indexes
</if>
```

I know that there are environment variables that can be set based on various conditions (like a certain user agent) and *I have been able to set them according to my needs*, bu I was not able to do a simple "if variable is set, then set Options +Indexes" statement

Suggestions? Pointers? Is this even possible? I do not have access to the Apache global configuration file.

Comment: I don't know about IF statement, but you can do a trick : enable directory endexing for everyone, and the ncheck with rewriting if someone requests a directory and he is not a 'certain user agent' then generate a forbidden error

Comment: No, this will not do, because the directory contains files that must be accessible to everyone, but for some special users I must enable the indexing to help them navigate the directories.

Comment: I just said to forbidden accessing the directory it self, not the files inside the directory

Comment: for example : domain.com/dir/ => forbidden , domain.com/dir/file.php => allow etc ...

Comment: @Yazmat: I see your point, but like I said, I need to enable indexing, so that the server will show (for some users) the directory content, not just serve the specific files found in the directory - [like this](http://www.redleopard.com/images/apache-directory-index.jpg)

Comment: then you don't see my point ... I did say to enable indexing for everyone by default and just block those who does not meet the required condition later with rewriting ...

Comment: Hmm... it may work.... you were right, I did not understood your point... will test and get back with a reply.. but sounds like will work

Comment: You are welcome ^^ glad it worked =)

Comment: @Yazmat, please write your solution as an answer, including the example.

Comment: None of the `<…>` container [directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html) matches your needs, so I doubt that what you have in mind can be formulated using such a syntax. I therefore would suggest an approach similar to Yazmat.

Comment: okay done, I posted an answer with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution, you can allow directory indexing to everybody, and then forbidden access to directories for those who don't meet some conditions using rewrite rules.

As an example (Forbidden directory indexing to everybody except googlebot) :

```
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !googlebot [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F]
```